# Silverstripe 4 doesn't find templates when using namespaces

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

Seems to be precious little info out there on how templates should be structured. I asked this question earlier but I think I can ask it better with code samples and remove my earlier attempt:

**mysite/_config/theme.yml**

```
SilverStripe\View\SSViewer:
  themes:
    - 'mytheme'
    - '$default'
```

**mysite/code/Page.php**

```
<?php

use SilverStripe\CMS\Model\SiteTree;

class Page extends SiteTree {

}
```

**mysite/code/PageController.php**

```
<?php

use SilverStripe\CMS\Controllers\ContentController;

class PageController extends ContentController {

}
```

**mysite/code/pages/HomePage.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\MainSite;

use Page;

class HomePage extends Page {

}
```

**/mysite/code/controllers/HomePageController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\MainSite;

use PageController;

class HomePageController extends PageController {

}
```

Then I have my theme. Structure like so:

```
theme
   mytheme
      templates
         **Page.ss**
         Layout
         Includes
         Vendor
            MainSite
               Layout
                  **HomePage.ss**
```

Assume that Page.ss contains $Layout. The issue I have is Page.ss is never picked up. I have confirmed Silverstripe is loading vendor/silverstripe/framework/templates/SilverStripe/Control/Controller.ss instead. I have tried various locations for Page.ss, including inside the same Vendor directory. I have also moved the entire structure to /mysite/templates.

The only way I have got the above to load a template is by removing namespacing from HomePage.php and simply following the SS3 structure for templates.

Comment: Looks good to me. Did you do a `dev/build`? If you don't have it yet, you should also put a `Page.ss` in `theme/mytheme/templates/Layout`, so that you get a login form to show up etc.

Comment: Multiple dev/builds. And manual destruction of the /tmp/cache. This simply doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't reproducible. Are you sure you've included everything exactly as it is in your project? For example, is your vendor actually "Vendor" ?

Comment: I think I discovered the issue just now. Adding namespaces to these classes broke the ClassName for the pages themselves. So the pages weren't actually looking for their templates at all. I had to use legacy.yml to force SS to alter the the old ClassNames to the namespaced ones. https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-upgrader#upgrading-database-references-to-now-namespaced-dataobject-subclasses

Comment: I also had this issue - but I found that it was resolved by running dev/build after namespacing and logging into the CMS, re-saving and publishing the pages in question.

Comment: This was really helpful there is still terrible documentation out there for this. Its totally unclear as to the best structure and namespace method.